# Image hosting for GIS exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

By nature of the questions generated on this stack exchange, I'm guessing images will become fairly common. I see the StackExchange [meta-thread on image hosting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19406/image-hosting-for-stack-overflow-answers), but this feels a bit hacky to me: it still leaves us with the task of maintaining image links over time. Any other recommendations for how we might perform image hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://imgur.com is also good and recommendable.

Comment: Looks like Jeff and the team implemented inline image hosting with imgurl, so this is all taken care of. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: @scw The only problem with imgur is that the image can potentially expire. http://imgur.com/faq#long I think it would be better if there was a way of hosting them within the site. Though an argument could be made if the image is being viewed that infrequently, if deserves to go....

Comment: @celen we have a network level pro account so images don't expire. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Comment: That's great!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using http://imageshack.us/ in the last couple of weeks. It's pretty quick and usability is good.

I'd like it better if it could be integrated with a local screenshot manager so I can skip the step of saving it to disk first.

Comment: If you don't mind maintaining it, you could store the screencaps (tried GreenShot?) in your dropbox public folder...  Wish there was a local client for Google Docs.

Comment: There is `google picasa create --title "My album" ~/Photos/vacation/*.jpg`, from [Google Command Line](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2010/06/introducing-google-command-line-tool.html). Not that I've used it yet. I don't see dropbox as viable because it means I'm responsible for the image in perpetuity when it really should belong to the community.

Comment: the other solutions SO recommends are no more stable than your dropbox images. I personally feel that if it matters SO should be hosting the images.  But that's been covered elsewhere with no resolution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site